# Changes in column table2 to be sum on table1 column - show attribute error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, escpos

I have two table
table 1 contain 4 columns pid, name, price, quantity
table 2 contain 5 columns cid, name, price, quantity,qunty1
I need a automatic sum in table1 quantity column when I update the value in table 2 quantity column

I tried this

```
cur.execute("Update custprodt, product set name1=? ,price1=?, quant1=? , remcont1=quant=?  where cpid=? , pid=? ",(self.var_pname.get(),self.var_price.get(),self.var_qty.get(),self.var_updatevalue.get()== self.var_qunt.get(),self.var_cpid.get(),self.var_pid.get(),))
```

it shows attribute error `self.var_qunt.get()`

I expecting automatic sum in table1 column when i changes value in table2 column

Comment: You can't update 2 tables with a single UPDATE statement.

Comment: ok how can i update